# how to mount power strip to brick wall

Tags: brick

I've got a power strip with no mounting holes. I need to mount it to a brick wall, as I have back probs and want to cut down on bending.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: A photo f the strip may help some have keyhole slots on the back some tabs on the ends. In brick a tapcon screw or other type of anchor may work but it depends on the type of mount required by the power strip. I have some that have brackets screwed to the wall that holds them in place so much more info is needed and a photo may also be helpful

Comment: Is there a reason you can't get something more suitable for permanent mounting, such as Plugmold?

Comment: Interior or exterior wall?   Rent or own?  <-- because landlords may frown on hammer-drilling holes for inserts.

Answer (score 3):

3M Scotch outdoor mounting tape may be something that will work for you. I've seen photos of the product used for attaching to brick, although the current collection of ad copy does not mention it. I've used the product to hold outdoor items and it's quite durable and strong.

The tape is a foam core with adhesive on both sides, allowing for irregularities in the surface. If it's necessary to remove for any reason, the foam has to be cut with a blade or some have used dental floss or similar cording to saw the foam.

Many locations have this product, [Home Depot included](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3M-Scotch-1-in-x-1-66-yds-Permanent-Double-Sided-Outdoor-Mounting-Tape-411DC-SF/100575385). Image courtesy of Home Depot.

[image: outdoor mounting tape]

If easier removal is required, 3M Dual Lock is a velcro-type fastener. The product is not hook-and-loop but rather is a set of plastic panels with super strong adhesive, containing mushroom-head stalks that interconnect for a quite strong attachment. It's a bit harder to find and a bit more expensive than the foam tape.